# Writing product $\prod_{i=1}^m (p_i^{n_i}-1)$ as a sum

Tags: number-theory, multiplicative-function

Suppose I have an integer $N$ with prime decomposition $N=\prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{n_i}$. How can I write

$$\prod_{i=1}^m (p_i^{n_i}-1)$$

as a sum that only depends on $N$, and not it's prime decomposition?

Clearly we have

$$\prod_{i=1}^m (p_i^{n_i}-1) = N - \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{N}{p_i^{n_i}} + \sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2=1 \\ i_1\leq i_2}}^n \frac{N}{p_{i_1}^{n_{i_1}} p_{i_2}^{n_{i_2}}} \dots$$

So it seems like we could write this as something like

$$\prod_{i=1}^m (p_i^{n_i}-1) = \sum_{d|N}\mu(d)\frac{N}{f_{N}(d)}$$

where $f_N(d)$ is a function that looks something like

$$f_N(d) = \prod_{p_i|d_i} p_i^{n_i}$$

My questions is, is there already a function like $f_N(d)$ in the literature that will satisfy this? If not, is there some other way to write $\prod_{i=1}^m (p_i^{n_i}-1)$ as a sum that only depends on $N$?

Comment: Your product seems to be [unitary totient function](https://www.google.com/search?q=unitary+totient+function). Once you know the name, you might be able to find some references where this function is discussed. It is mentioned, for example, in Sandor J., Crstici B. Handbook of number theory, vol.2, section 3.7.6.

Comment: According to the book I mentioned about, this function was introduced in the paper Eckford Cohen: *Arithmetical functions associated with the unitary divisors of an integer.*
doi: [10.1007/BF01180473](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01180473), [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/169870),
[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16459886105517439497&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5), [citations in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=16459886105517439497&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the formula $$\prod_{i=1}^m (p_i^{n_i}-1) = n \prod_{i=1}^m \left(1-\frac1{p_i^{n_i}}\right)$$ resembles the totient function, I thought that this kind of generalization of totient function might have been studied somewhere. The book Sandor J., Crstici B. *Handbook of number theory, vol.2*, has a chapter on generalizations of totient function, so I tried to look there. I will copy the relevant part from this book below.

I read there that the product from your question is sometimes called [unitary totient function](https://www.google.com/search?q=unitary+totient+function) and denoted $\varphi^*(n)$.
There are also other arithmetical functions related to [unitary divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_divisor).

Also a paper by Eckford Cohen was mentioned as a reference. (Exact reference is given below.) In this paper we can find the following:

> **Corollary 2.4.1.** $$\varphi^*(n)=\sum_{\substack{d\delta=n\\(d,\delta)=1}} \mu^*(d)\delta.$$
>   Where $\mu^*(n)=(-1)^{\omega(n)}$ is the unitary Möbius function and
>   $\omega(n)$ denotes number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

This sum over unitary divisors can be rewritten as 
$$\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\(d,\frac nd)=1}} \mu^*(d) \frac nd$$
which seems to be exactly the sum from your post. (Notice that unitary divisors are precisely the divisors of the form $p_i^{n_i}$.)

---

This is the part of Section 3.7.6 from Sandor-Crstici relevant to the question. (You can find much more facts about unitary versions of various arithmetical functions as well as further references in this book.)

> The *unitary analogue* of $\varphi(n)$ was introduced by E. Cohen [83] as follows. Let $(a,b)^*$
>   denote the greatest divisor of a which is a unitary divisor of $b$ 
>   (a divisor $r$ of $b$ is called unitary, if $\left(r,\frac br\right)=1$.)
>   If $(a,b)^*=1$, then $a$ is said to be *semi-prime* to $b$
>   Let $\varphi^*(n)$ be the number of positive integers $r\le n$, semi-prime to $n$. In fact,
>   $$\varphi^*(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d\mu^*(n/d) = \prod_{p^\alpha\mathrel{\|} n}(p^\alpha-1),$$
>   where $\mu^*(n)=(-1)^{\omega(n)}$ is the unitary Möbius function. For unitary divisors see also
>   1.9 of Chapter 1, 2.2.2 of Chapter 2, and 3.6.1 of Chapter 3. For the corresponding
>   notions of bi-unitary divisors and convolution, see 1.9 of Chapter 1, and 2.2.3 of
>   Chapter 2.
>
> [83] Eckford Cohen: *Arithmetical functions associated with the unitary divisors of an integer,* Math. Z. 74(1960), 66-80;
>   doi: [10.1007/BF01180473](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01180473), [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/169870), [MR 0112861](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0112861), [Zbl 0094.02601](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0094.02601).